# TexStudio paragraphs and hard returns

Tags: texstudio, return

Following a hard return, TexStudio sometimes gives me (A) a new line on which I can write and edit a full paragraph (e.g., lines 316 and 318 in the accompanying image), and sometimes given me (B) a series of lines that ought to register as a single line/paragraph (e.g., lines 301--310 in the accompanying image). Oddly, TexStudio treat lines 301--310 as a single line/paragraph when I first type it, but converts it to ten numbered lines after I save the file. This happens throughout my documents, with what should be single lines turning into multiple lines after saving. Any idea what's up?

[image: hard return and paragraph issue in TexStudio]

Comment: I don't think I understand. The whole purpose of Idefix -> Hard Line Break is to break a single long line (such as your line 316) over multiple short lines (such as your lines 301-310). If you select "smart scope selecting" it seems it  only acts on the current line/selected text though, not the entire document.

Comment: Check what you have in Options>Configure>Adv. Editor. There you find options for line wrapping.

Comment: Switched to "soft wrap at max characters" within the Avd. Editor Options. Thanks, @Sigur !